# What's wrong with my implementation on CountryData

Tags: curated-data, operators

I was wondering, *for which countries is the proportion of *Phone line users to population greater than or equal to that of the United States*?*

This is what I inputted below, but the list of countries seem too great.

```
countries=Last/@Take[Reverse[Sort[{CountryData[#,"PhoneLines"], #} & /@CountryData[]]], All]
```

Someone suggested I use "Select", but I have difficulties wording it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select[CountryData[], CountryData[#, "PhoneLines"]/CountryData[#, "Population"] >= 
   CountryData["USA", "PhoneLines"] / CountryData["USA", "Population"] &]
```

Gives:

```
{"Barbados", "Bermuda", "BritishVirginIslands", "Canada", 
"CaymanIslands", "Cyprus", "FalklandIslands", "France", "Germany", 
"Gibraltar", "Greece", "Guernsey", "HongKong", "Iceland", 
"IsleOfMan", "Jersey", "Liechtenstein", "Luxembourg", "Malta", 
"Monaco", "Montenegro", "Niue", "NorfolkIsland", 
"SaintPierreMiquelon", "SanMarino", "Slovenia", "Sweden", 
"Switzerland", "Taiwan", "UnitedKingdom", "UnitedStates", 
"UnitedStatesVirginIslands", "VaticanCity"}
```

**EDIT**

You can make `CountryData` `Listable` and use good 'ol `Pick`

```
SetAttributes[CountryData, Listable];    
Pick[CountryData[], CountryData[CountryData[], "PhoneLines"] / CountryData[CountryData[], 
"Population"], _?(# >= CountryData["USA", "PhoneLines"] / CountryData["USA", "Population"] &)]
```

Comment: +1 I sometimes hate Mma's verbosity `cd = CountryData; pl = "PhoneLines"; po = "Population";
Select[cd[], cd[#, pl]/cd[#, po] >= cd["USA", pl]/cd["USA", po] &]`

Comment: @Belisarius. I totally agree.

Comment: Almost golfed `cd = CountryData; 
r@x_ := cd[x, "PhoneLines"]/cd[x, "Population"]; Select[cd[], 
 r@# >= r@"USA" &]`

Comment: @Belisarius. Nice! I like it much better.

Comment: [I wonder why the pope has so many phones](http://i.imgur.com/3QutvPJ.png)

Comment: @ssch [Don't you know?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r8286teVgc)